# Not able to start oracle 10g service?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

It was working fine. Suddenly when I tried to start the server, it is showing this msg

```
E:\OracleXE\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN>net start OracleServiceXE
The service is not responding to the control function.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.
```

when i typed NET HELPMSG 2186.

> E:\OracleXE\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN>NET HELPMSG 2186
>
> The service is not responding to the control function.
>
> #### EXPLANATION
>
> The service cannot run your command at this time.
>
> #### ACTION
>
> Try the command again later.
>
> If the problem persists, stop and restart the service.
>
> However, if the problem continues after you have restarted the
> service, report t he problem. Be sure to include the name of the
> service and the command that was refused, to technical support.

I tried once again after restarting my computer, but no use

Comment: Check if you have appropriate user privileges. Make sure that the READ-ONLY attribute is not set on control files, data files and so on. Finally try to create a new service using ORADIM and try to start the the instance using PFILE from the previous one.

Comment: please explain me about oradim and how to use that ?

Comment: Hi . .. I am getting thi error now E:\OracleXE\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN>net start OracleServiceXE
The service is not responding to the control function.

Answer (score 0):

This is most commonly due to changing your machines name so the configuration stored in listener.ora is no longer correct. Update the machine name stored in it. The file location is (first part depends on where you installed it):

```
\Oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\NETWORK\ADMIN\listner.ora
```

Comment: i didnot change my machine name, but still i am getting same error. i even checked with my machine name and listner.ora file's mentioned name, both are same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the program as an administrator and see if it helps.

a)     Right click the program.

b)    Select Run as administrator.